# How can we explain relationship between bounded set and finite set?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

How can we explain relationship between bounded set and finite set? and relationship bounded sequence and finite sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Finite: has a bijection with the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ for some natural number $n$.
- Bounded (metric spaces): a set $A\subset M$, where $M$ is a metric space, is called bounded if it has a finite diameter, i.e. if $\sup_{x,y\in A} d(x,y)<\infty$

Obviously if a set (in a metric space) is finite then it is bounded. The converse is obviously not true. That's all I can see.